# What is the correct way to prevent MacBook Pro (mid-2010) from sleeping on lid close?

Tags: sleep-wake, closed-clamshell

I have MacBook Pro 13" mid-2010 (MacBookPro7,1), and sometimes I need it to work with the lid closed (long compilations, etc. while I'm on the go). I have tried InsomniaX, but it has no effect. I enable it via the menu bar icon and it displays "enabled", but, if I close the lid, my notebook will go to sleep in a dozen seconds or so. Any way I can prevent this? I know about the heat issue; it doesn't bother me.

Comment: Have you enabled Insomniax? When it is launched, it is disabled by default. Make sure that it's enabled.

Comment: Yes. As i stated in my question, InsomniaX is enabled.

Comment: Did you use InsomaniaX 2.0?

Comment: @Matt Just checked it - works! Please post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work with Lion, [InsomaniaX has been updated to version 2.0](http://semaja2.net/archives/206).

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "long compilations while I'm on the go" you mean something like "start a compile, stick laptop in backpack, remove at destination". Otherwise, I'd suggest just turning the screen off or locking it and leaving the clamshell open.

When you close the clamshell, the laptop will always go to sleep - the command to do so is at a deeper level than applications run at. (The no-sleep app I like, Jiggler, wiggles the mouse periodically to prevent sleep, but closing the lid will send the laptop to sleep anyway.)

Your best bet is to probably put the computer to sleep then wake it up when the screen is closed with a mouse or keyboard so it can continue to compile. (I've also seen people use a thin sheet of metal to hit the power button to wake the computer, but I've no experience with that.)

Comment: The power button pressing is not so good - holding it depressed will force an abrupt shut down. I have heard of people putting temporary bumpers in the screen or otherwise preventing the proximity sensors from detecting the lid being closed to good effect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying InsomniaX alternatives like **[Sleepless](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10564/sleepless)**?

(It's well maintained and has Lion support)

Comment: Not yet, it costs 10$ after all and it's website frightens me :). But i will try if nothing else works.

Comment: Yeah, the site is pretty ropey but I can vouch for Sleepless being effective.

Answer (score 1):

I just connect a USB keyboard and display adapter when I need it to keep running in [clamshell mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131).